# Swapping between two latex Files

Tags: pdftex, miktex, texmaker

I am working on two Latex files opened simultaneously. I am copying from one file and pasting it into another file. However, whenever I swap between two files, the mouse cursor always goes to the end of the document, and I have to search back the document again from where I had copied/pasted last.

This was not happening in previous Latex versions. However, in the latest upgraded version, I am getting this problem. It becomes very irritating.

I am using MikTex + Texmaker 5.1.2.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: This sounds like a Texmaker issue (or perhaps your computer's system settings). Does `Ctrl+click` work, for clicking on the pdf preview, so that the cursor goes to a specific spot?

Comment: I never faced this issue before. However, after updating MiKTeX and Texmaker, this issue arose.

Comment: You should probably report this to the Texmaker developers. The quick fix would be switching to a different editor. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/48973)'s a list of them. I like TeXstudio.

Comment: How to report it?